# How to overlay data points in a ggline plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, jitter

I have created a ggplot with different lines:

[image]

The code for this plot is the following:

```
ggplot(binodalbet) +
  aes(x = w.sal, y = w.tpc, colour = Category) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_path(linewidth=1) +
  scale_color_hue(direction = 1) +
  labs(
    x = expression(w[Salt]),
    y = expression(w[TPC]),
    title = bquote(Bet~":"~2~LA~"/"~K[3]~PO[4])) +
    scale_color_discrete(name="") + 
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50"), axis.text=element_text(size=20), title=element_text(size=24,face="bold"), legend.title=element_text(size=24, face="bold"),legend.text=element_text(size=22))
```

However, I want a specific set of points to just overlay the graph).

[image]

For which I have the following plot when built separately:

[image]

```
ggplot(data=expbet, aes(x = w.sal, y = w.tpc)) + geom_point()
```

I wonder if there is a way to putting the dot points overlaying the other plot.

Comment: Try `+ geom_point(data = expbet, aes(x = w.sal, y = w.tpc))` to add the layer with points to your first plot.

Comment: Aw. Sorry. Try `+ geom_point(data = expbet, aes(x = w.sal, y = w.tpc), inherit.aes = FALSE)` to not inherit the global aesthetics, i.e. to omit `color=Category`.